# Dynamic route segment in nextJS static js build

Tags: reactjs, redirect, browser, routes, next.js

is it possible to use dynamic routing path with nextJS, in a static build context?

Assuming my build is a set of html, js, css assets which could be hosted on any web server (Apache, Nginx, S3, Netlify etc...).

For instance I've got a path defined `/pages/[article].js/read` and I'd like to be able to use the structure: `/page/articleA/read` where `articleA` is a dynamic variable.

If that's feasible, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to use dynamic routes when using static-site-generation with nextjs. You have to use data-fetching method `getStaticProps` to fetch the data needed based on the dynamic route param. Additionally you have to use another function `getStaticPaths` to generate a list of `paths` for which nextjs will build static pages at build time. For example,

Suppose for page `/pages/articles/[articleId].js`, Here is what pseudo code might look like for you.

```js
// you have to generate and return a list of paths 
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    const articles = await /*Fetch the articles from backend or make a db query*/
    const paths = articles.map(article => ({ params: { articleId: article.id }}));

    return {
       paths,
       fallback: false
    }
}


export const getStaticProps = async (ctx) => {
   const articleId = ctx.params.articleId;


   // fetch the data using the article id and return as props

  return {
     props: /* fetched data */

  }
}

// create the page component and export it as the default export
```

You can read more about it in the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation). Keep in mind because the `fallback` is set to `false` nextjs will show a `404` page for any path that is not returned from the function `getStaticPaths`, You can read about `fallback` [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#the-fallback-key-required).

Comment: Thanks, will test it, that could be the solution

Comment: Yea, sure. Here is an [example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/blog-starter) from `nextjs` repo that uses SSG(static-site-generation) along with dynamic routes which might be similar to your use-case. Let me know if it was of any help or if you had any issues implementing it.